# Conversion from string "<IVCreateItemPriceListType><eCon" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

I am trying to copy string value to string but i am getting  error :

Conversion from string "

May be space is causing error. let me know how can remove the lines using VB.Net.

Code :

```
  Sub Main()

    Dim x As String = "<IVCreateItemPriceListType><eConnectProcessInfo xsi:nil=" + True + " /><taRequesterTrxDisabler_Items xsi:nil=" + True + " /><taIVCreateItemPriceListLine_Items><taIVCreateItemPriceListLine><ITEMNMBR>SAMSUNG</ITEMNMBR><CURNCYID>Z-US$</CURNCYID><PRCLEVEL>SUPPORT</PRCLEVEL><UOFM>Each</UOFM><UOMPRICE>80</UOMPRICE></taIVCreateItemPriceListLine><taIVCreateItemPriceListLine xsi:nil=" + True + " /></taIVCreateItemPriceListLine_Items><taIVCreateItemPriceListHeader><ITEMNMBR>SAMSUNG</ITEMNMBR><UOFM>Each</UOFM><PRCLEVEL>SUPPORT</PRCLEVEL><CURNCYID>Z-US$</CURNCYID></taIVCreateItemPriceListHeader></IVCreateItemPriceListType></eConnect>"



    x = x.Replace("<eConnectProcessInfo xsi:nil=" + True + " />", "")
    x = x.Replace("<taRequesterTrxDisabler_Items xsi:nil=" + True + " />", "")
    x = x.Replace("<taIVCreateItemPriceListLine xsi:nil=" + True + " />", "")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In your string and replace statement, you used

```
+ True +
```

without enclosed it in double quote `""`, it means that you're trying to add a string with a bool value and cause an exception. To fix the issue, replace the `+ True +` with

```
+ "True" +
```

**Update** Your code will look like this after edit:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim x As String = "<IVCreateItemPriceListType><eConnectProcessInfo xsi:nil=" + True + " /><taRequesterTrxDisabler_Items xsi:nil=" + "True" + " /><taIVCreateItemPriceListLine_Items><taIVCreateItemPriceListLine><ITEMNMBR>SAMSUNG</ITEMNMBR><CURNCYID>Z-US$</CURNCYID><PRCLEVEL>SUPPORT</PRCLEVEL><UOFM>Each</UOFM><UOMPRICE>80</UOMPRICE></taIVCreateItemPriceListLine><taIVCreateItemPriceListLine xsi:nil=" + "True" + " /></taIVCreateItemPriceListLine_Items><taIVCreateItemPriceListHeader><ITEMNMBR>SAMSUNG</ITEMNMBR><UOFM>Each</UOFM><PRCLEVEL>SUPPORT</PRCLEVEL><CURNCYID>Z-US$</CURNCYID></taIVCreateItemPriceListHeader></IVCreateItemPriceListType></eConnect>"



    x = x.Replace("<eConnectProcessInfo xsi:nil=" + "True" + " />", "")
    x = x.Replace("<taRequesterTrxDisabler_Items xsi:nil=" + "True" + " />", "")
    x = x.Replace("<taIVCreateItemPriceListLine xsi:nil=" + "True" + " />", "")

End Sub
```

You can use `Find and Replace` feature in visual studio to find `+ True +` and replace with `+ "True" +`

Comment: Thanks your reply...Let me know how can i remove that lines with out using replace.

Comment: @Havab what do you mean by `remove that lines without using replace`? Do you mean that you don't want to use `find and replace` feature in visual studio?

Comment: Actually i have to remove the lines using Remove method  from string insted using replace method. ...

Comment: I think replace the lines with "" is the best way to remove it in your case

Comment: how can i show with double code for the true value like = ex :    Dim value As String = "<eConnectProcessInfo xsi:nil=" + "true" + "/>" output like this :<eConnectProcessInfo xsi:nil=true />  Desired output :<eConnectProcessInfo xsi:nil="true" />

Comment: i got output..by using Dim y As String = "<eConnectProcessInfo xsi:nil=""true"" />"